# Display ellipsis in "100%" width div

Tags: html, css

First of all, there are many questions about this situation and I tried solving the problem but it didn't work out for me. So, let me explain...

This is what I have:
[image]

I have a div tag with `100% width` to display article's name and date. Name is floated left and date is floated right. Also, article is clearfixed. So, no problem with them.

Here is the HTML. By the way, `ell` is a helper class to add ellipsis. left, and right is a helper class for floating. Lastly, cf is for clearfix.

```
  <div class="article">
    <a href="{{post.url}}">
      <div class="article-meta cf">
        <div class="article-name left ell">{{post.title}}</div>
        <div class="article-date right">{{post.date | date: "%b %d, %Y"}}</div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Until here everything is perfect. Here is the CSS:

```
  .article{
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    &:last-child{ margin-bottom: 0; }
  }

  .article-meta{

    width: 100%;
  }

  .article-name{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 85%;
  }

  .article-date{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 9rem;
    // width: 15%;
    margin-left: 2rem;
    background-color: pink;
  }
```

I don't wanna use percentage in `.article-date`, because when I minimize the page, after some pixels, year part, goes to second line. Like in this picture:

[image]

So, width for date must be static and name must be fluid. And when date reaches title, name should have ellipsis.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. If someone is having the same problem, do exactly in this link.

http://jsfiddle.net/blai/7u59asyp/

```
.myTable {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.myTable:before {
    display: table-column;
    width: 100%;
    content: '';
}

.flexibleCell {
    display: table-cell;
    max-width:1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.staticCell {
    white-space: nowrap;
}


<div class="myTable">
    <div class="flexibleCell">A very long piece of content in first cell, long enough that it would normally wrap into multiple lines.</div>
    <div class="staticCell">Less content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

```css
.titleContent  {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vkh7yhw3/)

Comment: This is not what I need. I said it there, there is a helper class called `ell` for this.